# Style attribute not appearing

Tags: asp.net, positioning, vertical-alignment, alignment, response.write

I am displaying an image within each itme of a ListView. I want the image to be centered horizontally as well as vertically in a box. My code is as follows:

```
Protected Sub MembersLV_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewItemEventArgs) Handles MembersLV.ItemDataBound
        If e.Item.ItemType = ListViewItemType.DataItem Then
            Dim LogoImage As System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image = e.Item.FindControl("LogoImage")
            Dim LogoLink As HtmlControl = e.Item.FindControl("LogoLink")
            Dim di As ListViewDataItem = DirectCast(e.Item, ListViewDataItem)
            Dim ImageFileName As String = di.DataItem("FileName")

            Dim FilePath As String = String.Format("/Uploads/MembersDirectory/w125h85/{0}", ImageFileName)
            If File.Exists(Server.MapPath(FilePath)) Then
                LogoImage.ImageUrl = FilePath

                Dim BoxHeight As Integer = 101
                Dim BoxWidth As Integer = 138

                Dim B As New Bitmap(Server.MapPath(FilePath))
                Dim BHeight As Integer = B.Height
                Dim BWidth As Integer = B.Width

                Dim PaddingTop As Integer = Math.Ceiling(BoxHeight - BHeight) / 2
                Dim PaddingLeft As Integer = Math.Ceiling(BoxWidth - BWidth) / 2

                LogoLink.Attributes.Add("style", String.Format("padding: {0} 0 0 {1};", PaddingTop, PaddingLeft))
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

I simply calculate the amount of padding needed for the top and left of the image for it to be centered, and then add that padding as a style attribute to the surrounding  tag.

The code in the aspx file is as follows:

```
<a href='<%#Eval("Website") %>' id="LogoLink" runat="server">
    <asp:Image ID="LogoImage" runat="server" AlternateText='<%#Eval("Name") %>' />
</a>
```

When I ran this code, no padding had been applied to the `<a>` tags. So I did a quick check to ensure that `PaddingTop` and `PaddingLeft` were being calculted properly using `Response.Write`. Strangely, when I ran it this time, the style attribute appeared correctly! But without `Response.Write`, there is no style attribute.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just come back to have another look at this after a break from it. Having spent 5 minutes looking at it I suddenly realised I haven't specified the units for the padding! I have changed the code from:

```
LogoLink.Attributes.Add("style", String.Format("padding: {0} 0 0 {1};", PaddingTop, PaddingLeft))
```

to:

```
LogoLink.Attributes.Add("style", String.Format("padding: {0}px 0 0 {1}px;", PaddingTop, PaddingLeft))
```

This now works! Also, I have found that the `style` attribute is actually displayed in the source (if you View Source of the page), it's just not there if inspected in Firebug which threw me off the scent. I still don't understand why adding the line of Response.Write meant that the style attribute was applied, so if anyone could explain I would be interested to know why.